# Error: Navigation to http://localhost:8080/ was canceled by another one

Tags: javascript, adal, adal.js, playwright

I'm using `adal-angular` for my application, and as soon as it navigates to localhost, it redirects to another website to login. I received `(node:38052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Navigation to http://localhost:8080/ was canceled by another one`.

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const core = await context.newPage("http://localhost:8080/");

    await page.screenshot({ path: `example.png` });
    await browser.close();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
})();
```

This flow is regular AD Single Sign-On behavior, and I need to await the redirect to be over, and then insert user and password to obtain a token and call my API.

I tried using `goto` to no avail:

```
const playwright = require("playwright");

(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const core = await context.newPage("about:blank");
    const page = await core.goto("http://localhost:8080/");

    await page.screenshot({ path: `example.png` });
    await browser.close();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
})();
```

Here is a puppeteer example

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("http://localhost:8080", { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
  await page.screenshot({ path: "example.png" });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

At the end you get an image with the following:

[image: Azure AD Login]

Comment: There is an open issue here https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/629

Comment: thank you @hardkoded! Following